# how do i use malloc when I am in infinite while loop

Tags: c, malloc

I have a program that repeatedly asks user input a line and stores them in an array. 
I  know how to use dynamic memory allocation to make array if I can get a number of items to store at runtime. 
for example

```
char **array = (char**)malloc(numberOfItems * sizeof(char*));
```

but in my case, I do not know numberOfItems at runtime because I am getting input within a while loop which can be terminated by ctrl+D.

```
while(!feof(stdin)
{
    array[i] = (char*)malloc(167 * sizeof(char));
}
```

Any help, please.

Comment: You want `realloc`.  Lots of examples on the net.

Comment: By the way, if you use `feof()` that way, it's not going to work; see [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`realloc()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc) to grow the size of memory obtained through `malloc()`, `calloc()`, or `realloc()`.

```
int capacity = 10;
char **array = malloc(capacity* sizeof(char*));

int i = 0;
char line[256];
while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin)) {
    // Resize array when at capacity
    if (i == capacity) {
        capacity *= 2;
        array = realloc(array, capacity * sizeof(char*));
    }

    array[i] = malloc(167 * sizeof(char));
    i++;
}
```

A few related notes:

- Doubling the size of the container each time it grows is more efficient than growing by a constant amount. [Read more here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20448031/9614249).
- [Don't cast the result of `malloc()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/9614249)
- [Don't use `feof()` in a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5431941/9614249)

Hopefully that is enough to get you started!