# Is it guaranteed that C++ standard library containers call the replaceable new functions?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

If I replace all the `operator new` signatures that I can, at least on the implementations I have tested, I see that the standard containers call into my replaced versions to allocate memory.

Is this guaranteed by the standard? That is, would it be illegal for an implementation to use an optimized version which didn't call my replacement functions for the memory underlying the standard containers?

Comment: I believe that yes, at least in practice. However, I don't know well enough the C++ standard to cite it

Comment: The context of this question is: could `std::vector<T>` (with default allocator) use `realloc` and `calloc` instead of the weaker `new` API.  `new` can't take advantage of getting already-zeroed pages from the OS (avoiding `memset(0)`), or extending a mapping if possible, when nothing else is using that virtual address space.

Comment: Note that some containers (`std::string` in particular) may not store all elements in allocated memory, but might store some in the container object itself. Google "Small String Optimization" for details.

Comment: If that guarantee is important to your program, at the potential cost of performance loss, you also have the choice of allocating them yourself the way you want, and only storing pointers in the container

Comment: @PeterCordes I don't think this is possible. Even if global `operator new` is replaced, `std::vector<T>` still relies on allocator interface to do allocations and that interface does not provide a way to allocate default-initialized array or way to reallocate data - those operations are done by vector itself. In theory `std::vector<T>` could probably be specialized for standard layout types using standard allocator to use more effecient tecnique, but I don't think anyone does this.

Comment: @Ivan - yes, the allocator interface is limiting in this respect, but of course an implementation could implement an enhanced allocator interface which supports this and use those methods if they were detected but fall back to the standard-defined methods otherwise (similar to, but perhaps more general than, the idea you mention of specializing `vector` for the default allocator). Certainly implementations do already specialize several aspects of container behavior for trivially copyable types, so it isn't out of the question, but I agree that I don't think anyone does it yet.

Answer (score 27):

The default allocator for allocator-aware containers such as `std::vector<T>` is `std::allocator<T>`. This class template is described in section [default.allocator] of the standard. According to [allocator.members]/6 in C++14:

> the storage is obtained by calling `::operator new(std::size_t)`

So the global operator new is the one that you need to replace. If you overloaded `operator new` specifically for `T`, that overload will *not* be used by the default allocator.

Comment: So it would be illegal for a `std::vector` implementation to actually use `calloc` under the hood, even on a platform where `new` and `malloc` are compatible, unless the library + compiler could detect / prove that `::operator new(std::size_t)` hadn't been overridden?   (In which case the as-if rule should allow it with whole-program optimization).  The ["unspecified when and how `new` is called" language is enough to optimize away or merge some allocations](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator/allocate), but wouldn't allow bypassing `new` altogether, right?

Comment: @PeterCordes I'm pretty confident that that's the correct interpretation, yes.

Answer (score 7):

> Is this guaranteed by the standard?

As long as you don't use a custom allocator to create an instance of a container, I believe that is true.

From http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator

> The `std::allocator` class template is the default Allocator used by all standard library containers if no user-specified allocator is provided.

and

From http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator/allocate:

> Allocates `n * sizeof(T)` bytes of uninitialized storage by calling `::operator new(std::size_t)`