# Why std::vector doesn't use memcpy or realloc when resizing

Tags: c++, std, stdvector

I learnt that `std::vector` would explicitly call each element's copy-constructor during resizing, which if I understand correctly implies that it doesn't use `memcpy` or `realloc` under the hood, which was my first assumption. Is my understanding is correct? If so, why they needed to implement `std::vector` this way, isn't `memcpy` and better yet `realloc` would be the fastest options for resizing dynamical array under the hood?

Comment: Because you're not allowed to `memcpy` non-POD objects.

Comment: This is of course implementation dependant, but how do you know that your compiler/library does not apply such optimizations for POD types (under the hood) ?

Comment: Why would that be a problem in this case? All the internal buffers would still hold their allocations elsewhere and we would just `memcpy` their pointers.

Comment: I mean we don't create a new vector, just resizing the existing one, so no dangling pointers can be created for `non-POD`s inside

Comment: Stupid counterexample: `struct Foo { Foo() : ptr(&x) {}; int x; int *ptr; }`. If `memcpy` is used the pointer`ptr` becomes invalid. This kind of "action at a distance" is totally unexpected as part of a `push_back` on a `vector<Foo>`.

Comment: There's nothing to stop implementations of `std::vector` using `memcpy` or `realloc` if they chose to do so and the type of the elements allows that

Comment: As for `realloc`: this is simply not always possible. Memory allocators like to keep allocations packed together to reduce memory waste. You could of course provision gigabyte-sized holes inbetween memory allocations to maximize the chance of `realloc` working, but memory accesses performance would tank.

Comment: @Botje I know that `realloc` is not always possible, but there is always a way to check if it's possible before falling back to a more coslty`malloc+memcpy`?

Comment: The standard doesn't *require* an implementation of `std::vector` (or, possibly more accurately, its allocator) to use `memcpy()` and `realloc()`, but also doesn't  *forbid* such usage. The decision will be made by implementers of the standard library (e.g. that ships with each toolchain).  Practically, element types that explicitly manage a resource would often not work well with `memcpy()` and `realloc()`.  For other types, the choice would come down to engineering trade-offs - which won't necessarily (contrary to your claims) be a slam-dunk for `memcpy()` or `realloc()`.

Comment: It may use memcpy if the object is triviably copyable. For vectors of more complex types other mechanisms may be needed (like calling copy/move constructructors etc.). The main goal of vector is to aid with memory managment (avoid memory managment bugs), not to provide the fastest code (though any reasonable implementation will use whatever information on the type it has to select a pretty decent strategy)

Comment: Actually I dont understand the premise of the question. Why do you expect one way of copying the elements to be faster than another? I mean they both have to do the same: copy the elements. (yes, you might have reasons to believe `memcpy` to be faster, but imho they arent obvious).

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai In my understanding `memcpy` just copies raw block of bytes, all at once, which couldn't be more low-level and optimized. While options which call copy-contructors iterate through all elements and issue copy-constructor calls N times, which seems wasteful compared to `memcpy`. It's like O(1) vs O(N) kinda thing roughly speaking.

Answer (score 3):

The fundamental reason for having an explicit copy constructor for a type is that copying the bits won't work right for that type. So C++ container operations are specified in terms of copy construction. That doesn't mean that copying bits for types that are `memcpy`-able is prohibited; there's no way a conforming program can detect whether `int` values are copied via `memcpy` or by assignment. In fact, if you look into implementations of [`std::copy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) they typically **will** use `memcpy` for builtin types.

Comment: I was under the impression (and still is) that resizing std::vector is more relaxed operation in terms of how internal copying can be done. It still seems to me that in most cases even for non-trivially copyable types it's completely okay to use `memcpy` for resizing. But counterexample given by Botje `struct Foo { Foo() : ptr(&x) {}; int x; int *ptr; }` proves that at least in some cases it's not safe. Although I can't come up with any other example other then self-reference.

Comment: @simd -- from a language-lawyer perspective, skipping the copy constructor is detectable in a conforming program (the copy constructor might write out some debugging information), so the "as-if" rule doesn't allow skipping it. In order to allow it the standard would have to rigorously define the conditions under which skipping the copy constructor is allowed, which is, at best, a non-trivial task. But take heart: if a type that has a move constructor, reallocating will use the move constructor.

Comment: @PeteBecker "if a type that has a move constructor, reallocating will use the move constructor" - Only if it is declared to not throw exceptions (`noexcept`)  (IIRC).

Comment: Yeah, I was just so amazed that std::vector did call my copy-constructor on a completely trivial custom type (apart from std::cout logging in copy-contructor to check it), but now I realized that the custom copy-contructor did make this necessary  by its presence alone probably...

Comment: @simd By definition, if your type has a non-trivial copy constructor, it isn't trivial. If you log in the copy constructor, it isn't a trivial copy constructor.

Answer (score 3):

Compilers know how to optimize copy loops to calls `memcpy`.  That's not a problem; any type with a copy or move constructor that can optimize away, or that's trivially copyable, will get copied efficiently by real-world mainstream implementations when resizing `std::vector`.  (At least there's a very good chance of it, I haven't actually checked.

The big unsolved problem for efficient `std::vector` with huge sizes is using some kind of `realloc` that can just allocate new space if there's room for the existing allocation to grow.

Or for trivially-copyable types, using a system call like Linux `mremap` which can map the same physical pages at a new virtual address where there's room for it to grow in place, without loading or storing the actual data at all.  (Glibc `realloc` does this on Linux, and **it speeds up a microbenchmark by over 2x** of pushing a huge number of `int` elements and then reading them back, with gcc13 `-O3` + glibc on i7-6700k with DDR4-2666 on Linux, in a [C implementation of a dynamic array](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/288401/dynamic-array-of-int-in-c/288414#288414) where I compared `realloc` vs. `malloc`+`memcpy`+`free`.  And 70x fewer page faults, 9x fewer TLB misses.)

- The standard says `std::vector`'s default allocator has to use `new` internally, and the `new` operator can be overloaded by the user, so the as-if rule doesn't really allow doing something different like using `malloc` / `realloc` / `free` instead of `new`.  (Clang will sometimes optimize away an unused `new`/`delete` allocation, so apparently compilers don't need to consider `new` a visible side-effect, but if they do allocate, it has to be with `new`.)
- `new`/`delete` aren't required to be compatible with `malloc`/`realloc`/`free`, so using `realloc` isn't as-if compatible with `new`/`delete`.
- C++'s `new`/`delete` API sucks, only providing those two operations, not a `realloc` or `calloc`.  Or a try-realloc API for use with non-trivially-copyable objects: try to grow in place, return failure if it has to move to a different address.

  (Fresh pages from the kernel are known to be zero-filled, so there are many cases where `calloc` is as cheap as `malloc`, no memset needed.  This leaves the pages untouched, no page fault until first touched on systems with lazy allocation so it's efficient to allocate more space than you use.)  It makes no sense to omit those operations from the API; systems without a special way to do them can just implement them as alloc+copy+dealloc, or alloc+memset.

---

Related about this bad design of C++:

- [Does std::vector *have* to move objects when growing capacity? Or, can allocators "reallocate"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8003233/does-stdvector-have-to-move-objects-when-growing-capacity-or-can-allocator) - Howard Hinnant's answer says he and another C++ committee member proposed improvements that didn't catch on for C++11.
- [Why is there no reallocation functionality in C++ allocators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3105001/why-is-there-no-reallocation-functionality-in-c-allocators)
- [Is the poor performance of std::vector due to not calling realloc a logarithmic number of times?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49615076/is-the-poor-performance-of-stdvector-due-to-not-calling-realloc-a-logarithmic/50084320#50084320) (shows a custom allocator such that `std::vector<int, mmapalloc>` can grow efficiently for large sizes.)
- [Is it guaranteed that C++ standard library containers call the replaceable new functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46823224/is-it-guaranteed-that-c-standard-library-containers-call-the-replaceable-new-f)
- [Can the storage of trivially copyable objects be safely reallocated with realloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46838729/can-the-storage-of-trivially-copyable-objects-be-safely-reallocated-with-realloc) - language-lawyer formalism about copying bytes not creating an object in a formal sense.  That's not necessarily a problem for an implementation detail as part of the standard library on a system where it's known to work fine, though.

So basically, **the C++ standard requires `std::vector` to suck, and it's very hard to work around that per the as-if rule even for trivially-copyable types.**  Real-world compilers and their standard libraries just allocate + copy + deallocate when they have to grow, not even looking for unused virtual address-space contiguous with the existing allocation to grow into.

If you have very large arrays that actually do need to grow, `std::vector` is not an efficient choice.  (But it's so convenient, easy to use, and well-supported by other standard library stuff that it's often worth using even at the cost of performance.  It's so frustrating that over-simplification of C++'s allocator API vs. C's forces inefficiency even for trivially-copyable types, though.)

Answer (score 1):

The official declaration of `std::vector` is:

```
template< typename T,
          typename Alloc = std::allocator<T> >
class std::vector;
```

The allocator parameter - like any other STL container - has a default instance of `std::allocator`. This 2nd argument of the container controls the life-time (alloc/dealloc, construct/destroy) of the elements. The default allocator just may or may not use `std::realloc` as the implementation of hint version of its `allocate` member function.
Copying data in C++ involves a lot of consideration. In general it is bad practice to use explicitly `std::memcpy` for this purpose. If the object to be copied - or any none-static data members or base base classes - provides user-defined copy constructor(`T::T(T const&)`) and/or copy assignment operator(`T& T::operator(T&)`), then bitwise copy performed by `memcpy` leads to wrong results, possibility involving UB and all sort bugs. If on the other hand the type is trivially copyable, compiler is free to perform all sort of optimizations, including `memcpy` for copying on the type.
The `std::vector` keeps one data member of its allocator type, in case the allocator is not an empty type( the default type is empty and uses empty allocator optimization). So if special treatment of memory is needed, user can provide his own version of allocator (which may hold state variables per instance) to STL class:

```
struct my_T_alloc;//provide the definitions
struct my_T;//define the type
std::vector<my_T, my_T_alloc> m_T_vec;
```

The custome allocator should provide the corresponding memeber functions of [`std::allocator_traits`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator_traits).

Answer (score 1):

`memcpy` is not a problem:

- Compilers may insert `memcpy` for trivial types
- STL implementation may insert `memcpy` for trivial types.
- [P1144](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2024/p1144r10.html) proposes `std::is_trivially_relocatable` so that there's more types subject to relocating using `memcpy`

---

`realloc` is a problem because of the standard allocator interface, which doesn't have that. Some recent-ish movement to improve standard allocator in this direction was adding `allocate_at_least`, not quite `realloc`, but partly addresses the problem of unused space after the allocated memory.

---

I support the idea in the answer by Peter Cordes that very large arrays of trivial types are better to remap without copying memory. Always non-moving resize is way better than only potentially non-moving `realloc`.

(Though I'm not aware of any easy way of doing this in Windows, except mapping and then remapping a temporary file. A temporary file would still do, with proper flags the system would avoid to write it to the actual storage when possible)