# How to default-initialize without using new?

Tags: c++

I am trying to implement my own `std::vector` container, and I am using `realloc()` to resize it, to prevent deletion and reallocation every time. With the following code:

```
buffer = new T[n]();
```

This would default initialize each element of the array, and allow me to start accessing them right away. However, since the standard specifies that the memory `must be previously allocated by malloc(), calloc() or realloc()` to use `realloc()`, I cannot use `new`.

I know that `calloc()` will zero-initialize the memory, but I am not sure if that will have the same behavior as `new T[n]()`. What is the proper way to default-intialize with C style memory allocation?

Comment: "I am not sure if [`calloc()`] will have the same behavior as new T[n]()" Absolutely not. C functions know nothing about the C++ object lifetime model and are not sufficient to create valid C++ objects. IIRC, even for trivially constructable types, debate rages over whether the Standard indicates they can legally begin life via `malloc()` alone. And usually, if there has to be a debate about it, it's not safe to rely on yet.

Comment: "_I know that `calloc()` will zero-initialize the memory, but I am not sure if that will have the same behavior as `new T[n]()`._" One thing that is different is: it won't call constructors. In fact: none of C memory allocation routines will, since, well.. C doesn't have them.

Comment: You can't implement a std::vector like class with realloc.

Comment: @Fureeish The link you provide contradicts your statement.

Comment: You can't use `realloc` here unless your objects are trivially copyable. It seems you are severely underestimating the difficulty of the task you set out to complete.

Comment: Agreed with other comments, but still, if you want to try it, the next thing you need to learn is: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Placement_syntax

Comment: Relevant read: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8003233/3002139

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, no, zero-initializing memory is not the same as calling default constructors for the objects that that memory is supposed to hold. You **have to** call constructors. So `malloc` versus `calloc` doesn't matter in terms of correctness; so if you're going to go that route, use `malloc` -- it's faster.

Second, `realloc` won't work directly, because it doesn't know how to copy objects. Some objects can be copied byte-by-byte, and for those types, `realloc` is okay. But for most types, copying involves additional operations, and you have to use the copy constructor or copy assignment operator to do the copy. So `realloc` can be used in special cases, but not in general.

So, you're really limited to `malloc` and `free`, along with constructors (through placement `new`) and destructors.

Answer (score 0):

You can call any constructor with any kind of memory using this syntax:

```
::new (ptr) T(...arguments go here (if any)...);
```

You may have to use

```
#include <new>
```

It will call the constructor of T for a memory allocated at ptr.
for an array you will have to loop:

```
T* ptr=(T*)malloc(sizeof(T)*n);
for(int i=0;i<n;++i)
   ::new(ptr+i) T();
```

But with this, DO NOT CALL delete ! You will have to explicitly call the destructor for each item and then free the memory with the correct function:

```
for(int i=0;i<n;++i)
   (ptr+i)->~T();
free(ptr);
```

In case of realloc, you must be sure that the T object can be relocated without any problem (byte-to-byte copy OK). It should be safe for struct with simple data type.